# I'm looking for a psychology term related to behavior motivation or inducement

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms

Its a single word that essentially means something like *motivation*.

There are both positive and negative versions of it like *positive something* - motivate by giving reward when someone does a good thing, or *negative something* - motivate by punishing when someone does a bad thing.

I knew that word a long time ago, but presently beats my memory! Can you help me out?

Comment: Reward and motivation seem to me more scientific than deterrent and incitement, otherwise I'd suggest them.

Comment: Not *deterrent* or *incitement*. The word was something else.

Comment: Thanks, but I got it. Its **Reinforcement**!

Comment: I knew that you were thinking of "reinforcement", but be careful... it doesn't mean   "motivation,"

Comment: Right. It means, respectively, _reward_ (positive) or _punishment_ (negative).

Comment: Questions about specialized terminology will be better-answered on specialist stacks; I might recommend [CogSci.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) in this case.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - Actually positive/negative reinforcement has nothing to do if it's good or bad. It has to do with receiving (positive) or giving up (negative) something for behavior. Punishment can be both positive (e.g. spankings) or negative (e.g. No Xbox for a week). Likewise rewards can be positive or negative reinforcement. You lose pounds when you go on a diet and exercise (negative). You have more energy when you diet and exercise (positive).

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about positive/negative reinforcement/punishment. But, be careful how you're using those terms! Quick breakdown:

- positive - add something
- negative - take something away
- reinforcement - encourage behavior
- punishment - discourage behavior

So, to combine those two axes:

- positive reinforcement - *give* something to *encourage* behavior, e.g., "Here's this candy for raking the yard."
- negative reinforcement - *take* something to *encourage* behavior, e.g., "I'll stop screaming in your ear if you sweep the floors."
- positive punishment - *give* something to *discourage* behavior, e.g., "You get a spanking for breaking the TV."
- negative punishment - *take* something to *discourage* behavior, e.g., "I'm taking your XBox away for a month because you hit your brother."